# Command data field of Send LOAD

Tags: c#, smartcard, javacard, smartcard-reader, globalplatform

I want to install applets on Java Card with C# program. I've successfully steps 1-4.

I'm having trouble at step `5. Send LOAD (80 E8 00 00 XX..)`, What is `Command data field (C482099B010023DEC..)` of `LOAD` come from?

**I tried read the .cap file as parameters but failed**. Thanks.

```
To install the applet in Java Card:
1. Open the reader.
2. Send SELECT to select ISD（AID）
3. Initiate the Secure Channel (INITIALIZE UPDATE and EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE).
4. Send INSTALL[for Load] (80 E6 02 00 XX..).
5. Send LOAD (80 E8 00 00 XX..).
6. Send INSTALL[for Install] (80 E6 0C 00 XX..).
```

//

```
<<80 E8 00 00 FF C4 82 09 9B 01 00 23 DE CA FF ED 02 02 04 00 01 07 4C 6F 79 61 6C 74 79 11 4C 6F 79 61 6C 74 79 43 61 72 64 41 70 70 6C 65 74 02 00 21 00 23 00 21 00 0F 00 1F 00 EA 00 0E 07 1B 00 3E 00 BD 00 00 02 19 10 AF 00 0C 00 06 00 22 03 01 00 04 00 1F 03 02 01 07 A0 00 00 00 62 01 01 02 01 07 A0 00 00 00 62 01 02 02 01 07 A0 00 00 00 62 02 01 03 00 0F 01 0B 4C 6F 79 61 6C 74 79 43 61 72 64 00 55 06 00 0E 00 00 00 80 03 0A 00 06 07 01 00 00 00 63 07 07 1B 00 05 40 18 8C 00 0C 18 03 89 00 18 03 89 01 18 06 11 00 80 03 8D 00 0E 94 00 00 10 87 02 18 05 03 8D 00 0D 87 03 18 05 8D 00 0F 87 04 18 8F 00 0A 3D 06 10 08 8C 00 0B 87 05 18 10 08 90 0B 87 06 18 10 10 90 0B 87 07 18 03 88 08 18 03 88 09 18 8B 00 11 7A 05 30 8F 00 12 3D 18 1D 1E 8C 00 13 3B 7A 02 21 18 8B 00 14 00
>>00 90 00


5. LOAD
------------------------------------------------------------
CLA                 80  GlobalPlatform command
                        No secure messaging
                        Logical channel 0
INS                 E8  LOAD
P1                  00  More blocks
P2                  00  Block number
Lc field            FF  length of data field
Command data field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
Le field            00
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add there the extracted CAP file content in a specific order.

[This logic is used](https://github.com/kaoh/globalplatform/blob/master/globalplatform/src/globalplatform.c#L2439) to trigger the loading process. The tag C4 is important + the length [which is then handled in this function](https://github.com/kaoh/globalplatform/blob/master/globalplatform/src/globalplatform.c#L2243).

[The load file is extracted to a buffer with this logic](https://github.com/kaoh/globalplatform/blob/master/globalplatform/src/loadfile.c#L42), basically the CAP, which is zip file, is extracted and all components according to the Java Card Specification are concatenated [which is done here](https://github.com/kaoh/globalplatform/blob/master/globalplatform/src/loadfile.c#L121).

It can be more complex if a load file signature is used or the load file should be encrypted but this is rarely used.